# libipq not supported in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c, ubuntu-12.04, iptables, packet, raw-sockets

I have the requirement of altering packets as a part of my University's research project and came across two libraries. which are `libnetfilter_queue` and `libipq` which is the deprecated version. `libnetfilter_queu`e documentation is next to zero on packet alteration and the only good documentation I came across is done via `libipq`.

Thus, when I run my code I get the error passer: Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported which I found out that is due to the fact that `libipq` is not supported in the new linux kernels.

My query is, is there a work around to make `libipq` work with `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` or any reference to documentation or tutorials that would help implement packet alteration via `libnetfilter_queue`.

I was at this for some days and could not find solution. you help will be very much appreciated. :)

Thank you very much :)

P.S: the question is also posted over here  ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/430234/libipq-not-supported-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `ip_queue` module is gone, then you can't use `libipq`, as it leverages that module directly; so no, there's no workaround unless you install an older kernel that still has the `ip_queue` module.

That said, you've mentioned absolutely nothing about what you've actually tried. If you start from a basic [`libnetfilter_queue`](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/nfqnl__test_8c_source.html) example, when you're setting the verdict, you should be using [`nfq_set_verdict`](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html#gae36aee5b74d0c88d2f8530e356f68b79), passing in the `data_len` and `buf` parameters containing the swizzled packet data.

Comment: Thank you for this very descriptive answer :) I tried a few codes and from your reply I knew I was heading the wrong way. Thanks again and I will update the question with what I have done :) +1

Comment: Sir, small query..i was experimenting on your information and is it possible to alter the header information via the `nfq_set_verdict` as I did not quite get the concept of it :)

Comment: as long as you used `nfq_set_mode(qh, NFQNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff)`, you should have an entire copy of the payload of the packet once you retrieve it. When you retrieve the packet using `nfq_get_payload()`, it will contain all the packet data, including the header, and for example if you want to get the ip header from the data, you could cast the pointer returned to a `struct iphdr *`

Comment: Thanks alot sir!!! your help just saved me!! THANK YOU!! I wish I could give your answer a few more thumbs up :D